Genesis 28:3 a congregation of peoples
The phrase 'Company of Peoples' in Genesis 28:3 is similar to the Greek word in the NT for congregation. I think Genesis 28:3 refers to nations of people, but since it is similar to ekklesia, is it possible to tie qāhēl to ekklesia?

Short Answer: It is possible to tie the two together in terms of meaning and function.

When the Hebrew Bible was translated into Greek in the 3rd and 2nd
centuries BC the translators used ekklesia to render the Hebrew word
qahal which also means assembly or community. [a]


Ekklesia is used many times throughout the LXX to translate the Hebrew
word qahal (or kahal). Recall that the LXX is using Greek to translate
the Old Testament, the same Greek as used in the New Testament. What
we end up with is an entire Bible written in Greek. [b]


Take Psalm 22:22 for example from the Interlinear Greek English Septuagint Old Testament (LXX)


Now if we look at it in the Hebrew Interlinear Bible (OT) we see:

Here we see קָהָל translated as εκκλησίας.
I want to note the Strong's definition of both words:
ἐκκλησία, ας, ἡ (ekklésia)
Definition: an assembly, a (religious) congregation
Usage: an assembly, congregation, church; the Church, the whole body of Christian believers.
קָהָל (qahal) Definition: assembly, convocation, congregation
This being said, it is interesting that in Genesis 28:3 the word לִקְהַ֥ל liq-hal (an assembly) is translated in the LXX as συναγωγή (synagōgas) from sunagógé meaning: a bringing together, by ext. an assembling, hence a synagogue, rather than from qahal.

EDIT: As Dan mentioned, the meanings of these words have changed over time.

Unofficial groups in the Greco-Roman world that I (and others)
typically call “associations” used a variety of terms to describe
themselves. Some of the favourite Greek terms were synodos (“synod”),
koinon, synergasia (“guild”), thiasos (“cult-society”), and mystai
(“initiates”). Today, when people (including many scholars) hear the
term synagogue or head-of-the-synagogue (archisynagogos) they tend to
assume some Jewish group (or building) is in mind. However, the term
synagogue (stemming from the Greek synagō, meaning to gather or bring
together) was also used by other “pagan” associations and was not
necessarily a sign of Jewish connections. [c]



1 . I would add that the meanings of these words changed over time.  The root  word for synagogue was retained in the Christian "synod," and there were once "synagogues" where pagan worshipers gathered. Today the term is reserved to Jewish worship. https://www.philipharland.com/Blog/2005/08/those-other-pagan-synagogues/


Jason, thank you for the response. I hope it is not a stretch then to suggest that God was pointing to the NT church from Genesis 28:3 in which Isaac made a prophetic statement to equate Company of Peoples with the church.

@Puddinhead I think it's possible based on the linguistics. However, we have to remember that these are two different languages and the culture likely changed drastically over the span of time. Because of that it's hard to give a definitive answer. That being said, I think one could indeed see a connection.

@DanFefferman Thank you. I appreciate it! I have taken your suggestion and added an edit.
